# use selenium to login to website through cookies

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to use selenium to login to this webpage: https://betsapi.com/rs/pinnaclesports/2852774/BOOM-ID-v-Neon-Esports

I created this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

u = 'https://betsapi.com/rs/pinnaclesports/2852774/BOOM-ID-v-Neon-Esports'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(u)
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

I used the chrome extension 'EditThisCookie' to get the cookies and I store them into list of dictionaries:

```
cookies =[
{
    "domain": ".betsapi.com",
    "expirationDate": 1603651291.620966,
    "hostOnly": False,
    "httpOnly": True,
    "name": "__cfduid",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": False,
    "session": False,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "d6db2b7ec158b5623df65e61e0fc709da1601059292",
    "id": 1
},
{
    "domain": ".betsapi.com",
    "expirationDate": 1636449445,
    "hostOnly": False,
    "httpOnly": False,
    "name": "__gads",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": False,
    "session": False,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "ID=c1df2d77d8aeb6b0-22ec198446a60058:T=1602753445:RT=1602753445:S=ALNI_Mb9ZXRFX374-MAx-ZWd8WXHlLbNHA",
    "id": 2
},
{
    "domain": ".betsapi.com",
    "expirationDate": 1665999953,
    "hostOnly": False,
    "httpOnly": False,
    "name": "_ga",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": False,
    "session": False,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "GA1.2.1329605927.1601059303",
    "id": 3
},
{
    "domain": ".betsapi.com",
    "expirationDate": 1603014353,
    "hostOnly": False,
    "httpOnly": False,
    "name": "_gid",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": False,
    "session": False,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "GA1.2.137866329.1602927773",
    "id": 4
},
{
    "domain": ".betsapi.com",
    "hostOnly": False,
    "httpOnly": False,
    "name": "sid",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": False,
    "session": True,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "7jq0ph5rho4cdat4cngjmdmeg9",
    "id": 5
},
{
    "domain": "betsapi.com",
    "expirationDate": 1614199343,
    "hostOnly": True,
    "httpOnly": False,
    "name": "hstpconfig",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": True,
    "session": False,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "eyJJRCI6IjY2NTE4NDM2dWk1ZjZlMzllOTM3NjQ4IiwiQ1RSIjoiVE4iLCJSZWdpb24iOm51bGwsIkJyb3dzZXIiOiJDaHJvbWUiLCJQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldpbmRvd3MiLCJNb2JpbGUiOjAsIkJvdCI6MCwicmVtb3RlX2FkZHIiOjMzMDMwODcxOTQsIkxhc3RVcGRhdGUiOjE2MDEwNTkzMDV9",
    "id": 6
},
{
    "domain": "betsapi.com",
    "expirationDate": 1602999953,
    "hostOnly": True,
    "httpOnly": False,
    "name": "hstpcount45424",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": True,
    "session": False,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "eyJDbGljayI6MCwiQ291bnRlciI6MX0%3D",
    "id": 7
},
{
    "domain": "betsapi.com",
    "expirationDate": 1603219304,
    "hostOnly": True,
    "httpOnly": False,
    "name": "lasttrack45424",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": True,
    "session": False,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "1",
    "id": 8
},
{
    "domain": "betsapi.com",
    "hostOnly": True,
    "httpOnly": False,
    "name": "tz",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": False,
    "session": True,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "Europe%2FBerlin",
    "id": 9
}
]
```

The code open the driver but don't login, how I can login using cookies ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi instead of extension,

use `driver.get_cookies()` into file and use this file to login again as `driver.add_cookie()`

or use pickle files

check this

> https://intellipaat.com/community/6078/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver